# How to read barcode from ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm not sure, is this possible or not? I want to scan barcode from within ASP.NET website. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I would provide a file upload control and then do some barcode "OCR" on the server.

Comment: check this out: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: http://silverlightbarcode.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need a scanner and the relevant software to interact with the scanner. Most hand held scanners simply output the text into whatever field is in focus, so this could be Notepad, Word, or even a textbox in your app.

Best approach is to find a scanner that suits your needs and then look into the Driver software it provides.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use Flash to gain access to a user's web cam and have them place the barcode infront of the camera. I'm sure Silverlight can do this as well.

No matter how you cut it, though, you're going to need to use some sort of third-party control, whether Flash/Silverlight, Java applet, or browser extension/addon.

An alternative would be to use a specific brand of barcode scanner whose software can insert the results into an arbitrary textbox.