# Reading barcode in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am Developing asp application version 4.5.Currently i have an requirement which will read an document which will have 2D and linear barcode both.Can anyone suggest an DLL,through which i can read both 2D and linear barcode.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to go with proprietary API's to achieve secure and faster performance.

you can find many free like codeplex https://freebarcode.codeplex.com/
To workaround and to understand how it works please refer [This Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42852/Reading-Barcodes-from-an-Image-III)

[BarcodeLib](http://www.barcodelib.com/csharp/) also has some good capabilities.

Comment: The link was helpful,but i have an pdf which has both 2D and Linear barcode..how should i read that...

Comment: @NileshKulkarni you mean you already encoded and printed barcode on the paper and want to read it is it?

Comment: are you using camera or laser beam? if it is a laser beam you have to get API from vendor. see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7384858/3583859

Comment: :Thank you very much for your help,the problem is solved,i have use bytescout library to read the barcode and also used A-pdf scan and spilt to split the pdf.